# Rendering error safari tilt.js over fixed element

Tags: safari, rendering

There is a view (only on Safari) error when tilt object is over a fixed element.

https://codepen.io/imagica/pen/zYPYbbJ

```
.header{
      height: 100px;
      width: 100vw;
      background: red;
      position: fixed;
}
```

any ideas how to fix this?

Marco